# How to use a recursive query inside of a function?

Tags: postgresql, recursion, plpgsql, stored-functions

I have a working recursive function down below that returns the hierarchy of a .Net Element, in this example 'ImageBrush'

```
    WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT id, name, dependent_id, 1 AS level
    FROM dotNetHierarchy
    WHERE name = 'ImageBrush'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT g.id, lpad(' ', r.level) || g.name, g.dependent_id, r.level + 1
    FROM dotNetHierarchy g JOIN r ON g.id = r.dependent_id
    )
    SELECT name FROM r;
```

Now I want to use it inside a function, where the input is a text like 'ImageBrush' which gets inserted in the WHERE statement of the recursive query.

The table dotNetHierarchy has 3 columns: id, name, dependent_id

The following didn´t work with PgAdmin just querying forever without an error:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hierarchy(inp text) RETURNS 
    TABLE (id int, name text, id int, lev int) AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT id, name, dependent_id, 1 AS level
        FROM dotNetHierarchy
        WHERE name = inp
      UNION ALL
        SELECT g.id, lpad(' ', r.level) || g.name, g.dependent_id, r.level + 1
        FROM dotNetHierarchy g JOIN r ON g.id = r.dependent_id
        )

        SELECT name FROM r;
        return;
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I tried searching google for using recursive querys in functions, but the few results proved not to be working.

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything. You would at least need a `return query`, but it's more efficient to use a `language sql` function to encapsulate a query:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hierarchy(inp text) 
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, name text, id int, lev int) AS
$BODY$
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
  SELECT id, name, dependent_id, 1 AS level
  FROM dotNetHierarchy
  WHERE name = inp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT g.id, lpad(' ', r.level) || g.name, g.dependent_id, r.level + 1
  FROM dotNetHierarchy g JOIN r ON g.id = r.dependent_id
)
SELECT name
FROM r;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```